# Can we call http.Error() before a webSocket connection upgrade?

Tags: http, go, websocket, gorilla

I’m using Gorilla WebSockets.

I pass some parameters in the url to the `HandlerFunc` and I need to check that they are valid.

If they are, I upgrade the connection to a webSocket and use it.

If they aren’t, I would like to call `http.Error` to report the error to the user.

Is this the right way of doing this ?

Here is an example code:

```golang
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{} // use default options

func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    keys, ok := r.URL.Query()["key"]
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, "missing key parameter", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("upgrade:", err)
        return
    }
    defer ws.Close()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your question seems to be what would happen if you ran the code you already have. Have you tried just trying it? What happens?

Comment: @Adrian code is too complex and work in progress. I can’t test it. I should eventually create a small test code, but I found it simpler to ask here and I would like to have the norm. It’s not because it would work with some webSocket X and client Y that it would be the norm. I would not ask if I could test it my self.

Comment: Returning a 404 response is the correct way to handle this scenario.  What problem did you encounter?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks. I’m just writing the code. I didn’t test anything yet.